# choosing right data structure

Tags: visual-c++, com, data-structures, mfc

I need to know

1. What is the best data structure to use when transferring and storing large amounts of data across different COM objects in MFC application.

(the data is usually large strings, xml files, images etc)

2. Is there any memory issue if I use CList, CMap etc

Thanks

Comment: What kind of data is it? Are the data COM objects themselves?

Comment: @rwong the data is usually large strings, xml files, images etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)   Data structures to use is totally depend on the application and data needs to be store. Which ever data structure you will use is not going to affect the result but it defiantly affect runtime algorithm. I liked the following statement so pasting here.

**The universal properties of data structures are the amount of memory used in storing the contents, and the time and additional memory each operation takes. You come to know those for some important kinds ofdata structures and look for a fit with the requirements on footprint or responsiveness.**

2)    Personally I dont think their will be any memory issue if you properly manage data/objects stored into heap/stack from the data structure.